# How to get the ID of the specific logged in user without using session functions, ONLY API method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

developers! I just want to ask a question (this is my first time to ask. :) ). What are the ways/methods/codes did I going to use to get the ID of a specific logged-in user using REST API method, just API only. Without using session functions. Hopefully you all of you can help me to my problem. Thank you so much!

This is for my project to my client. I'm using CodeIgniter and REST API for this project. This is the code I've made.

```
$user_id = $this->user_model->get_user_id_from_username(!empty($this->post('id'))?$this->post('id'):$this->response(array('error'=>'id cannot be empty'), 404));
```

It must display an ID number of a user who logged in to the system, but there are error always. It always displayig

> "error::id cannot be empty"

.

Comment: What's in `$this->post('id'))`? Seems like it is always empty then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_id=$this->user_model->get_user_id_from_username(empty($this->input->post('id'))?$this->input->post('id'):

$this->response(array('error'=>'id cannot be empty'), 404));
```

Comment: Giving a little more context as tough why this code would answer the question would be really appreciated